# Only variables should be passed by reference in php

Tags: php, pass-by-reference, php-5.3

I have the following code :

```
    $_SESSION['aParties'] = time();
    $aParties[] = $_SESSION['aParties'];
    error_log(print_r($aParties,true), 3, "/var/tmp/error.log");
    $first = reset(ksort($aParties));
```

The array aParties is like this :

```
Array
(
  [0] => 1433841062
)
```

But I get the error :

```
'Only variables should be passed by reference in the method ksort'
```

Help me please! Thx in advance

Answer (score 2):

You need to do it as

```
ksort($aParties);
$first = reset($aParties);
```

> Note: There is no reference sign on a function call - only on function definitions. Function definitions alone are enough to correctly pass the argument by reference.

[Check Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php)